# React Native ShouldComponentUpdate not firing between Redux Props Changes

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In optimizing my component for performance, I noticed that sequential shouldComponentUpdate calls were seemingly missing the prop change from my redux store. An example being:

In props:

```
uiBehavior: {
  shouldShow: false,
}
```

Redux Action:

```
fireActionToShow()
```

Redux Reducer:

```
case ActionType.UPDATE_UI_BEHAVIOR: return {...state, shouldShow: true}
```

Then I'm seeing:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  // Would expect to at some point see:
  this.props.shouldShow === false
  nextProps === true

  // Instead, only seeing
  this.props.shouldShow === false
  nextProps === false

  // then
  this.props.shouldShow === true
  nextProps === true
}
```

** Note that this clearly isn't the code, just an example

It seems to me that a prop change isn't causing a rerender attempt, or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Expanding for clarity, here is some of the real code:

*** the event in the Action updates the uiBehavior prop on the redux store.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { uiBehavior } = this.props;

    if (!_.isEqual(uiBehavior.lockAttributes, prevProps.uiBehavior.lockAttributes)) {
      console.log('Lock has changed.'); // This never gets called
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = function(state){
  return {
    uiBehavior: state.uiBehavior,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SlotMachine)
```

*** UPDATE

JS Call:

```
this.props.setGeneralUiKeyValue('lockAttributesInCart', !lockAttributes);
```

Action:

```
export const setGeneralUiKeyValue = (key, value) => { return { type: GENERAL_UI_UPDATE, key, value }}
```

Reducer:

```
export const uiBehavior = (state = {}, action) => {
    let newUiState = {...defaultState, ...state}
    switch (action.type) {
        case uiActionTypes.GENERAL_UI_UPDATE:
            newUiState.general = newUiState.general || {};
            newUiState.general[action.key] = action.value;
            return newUiState
        default:
            return newUiState;
    }
    return newUiState
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what the issue is from the pseudocode provided, do you have a full working example?

Comment: Updated! Does that help make it understandable?

Comment: Could it be that `uiBehavior` is changing but `lockAttributes` isn't? Can you also include the action and reducer?

Comment: Updated. It seems to be changing, since I am seeing it change in the shouldComponentUpdate call, it's just that I never see the middle state where it is false, and then nextProps shows it as true.